# Display data on one page with using MudDataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, mudblazor

I have a class that has more than 10 properties. I need MudDataGrid to display all this data on one page.
For me, it stretches this data beyond the screen and has to scroll to the left. Is it possible to make words in row cells wrap to fit within the web page window?

Tried to apply css styles for table and rows. I'm not strong in UI, but I'm sure this problem can be solved...

Answer (score 1):

As you have provide no code, here's a very simple `MudDataGrid` that demonstrates text wrap on long data rows:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<MudDataGrid Items="@Elements">
    <Columns>
        <PropertyColumn Title="Country Name" Property="x => x.Name" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Description" />
    </Columns>
</MudDataGrid>

@code {
    private IEnumerable<Country> Elements = new List<Country>()
        {
        new() {Name="UK", Description ="33 3j3j3j j3j 3j2qjhwhw  2h2h2 2h 2 2h2 2h2h2h2h2hhwjkwj hqwkjqwkjhq  qwkjqwkjh qw qwkj  k qwhqkwjhqwkjh wqh akklAS kljAKL al lkAa ALKJ alkALK a "},
        new() {Name="Spain", Description="33 3j3j3j j3j 3j2qjhwhw  2h2h2 2h 2 2h2 2h2h2h2h2hhwjkwj hqwkjqwkjhq  qwkjqwkjh qw qwkj  k qwhqkwjhqwkjh wqh dslkjsdaklj kljsdl sdlk slkjsd dsa lksad  "},
        new() {Name="Portugal", Description="33 3j3j3j j3j 3j2qjhwhw  2h2h2 2h 2 2h2 2h2h2h2h2hhwjkwj hqwkjqwkjhq  qwkjqwkjh qw qwkj  k qwhqkwjhqwkjh wqh asLKSALKASkl aLKJSAL ALKJAS salk lALKSLKJAs  "},
        };

    public record Country
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Which wraps as expected.

[image]

What are you doing to stop wrapping?